# Word for many people doing the same (silly) thing

Tags: single-word-requests

An example: Tourists at the leaning tower of Pisa all doing the same (clichéd) pose.

[image]

Is there a single word for such behavior? It's not a *flash mob*, obviously, because it happens all year 'round. It's not *mirroring* because it's not subconscious behavior, but something very intentional. It's not *synchronicity* because it's not a spontaneous thing. It's not *aping* or *copycatting* either, since people aren't (necessarily) mimicking anyone in particular.

I suppose it's *ritualistic*, but that seems too serious for something so silly.

I suppose this behavior constitutes a *meme*, but I'm wondering if there's a better word for it. Or for the act itself; the act of participating in and propagating the meme.

Comment: It's not just tourists that can't resist the "same old tired/lame joke". There's something about some of us humans that makes us incapable of resisting making the obvious joke even though we know it's been done a thousand times before. On the other hand, why take the same stand-in-front-of-it-and-smile picture when you can do something more interesting. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=posing+with+statues&iax=1&ia=images

Comment: I think "cliched", which you mention in your question text, is actually the best word for this.  You could also say "predictable".

Comment: This is **madness**. Or fad, craze, fashion, trend?

Comment: They're doing the same thing, you say? They are "enjoying themselves", I believe

Comment: Not any better than “meme,” but you could say [“It’s **a thing!**”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=it%27s%20a%20thing) “Tourists taking the same silly photos? It’s been **a thing** since Kodak made the first Brownie!”

Answer (score 2):

The tourists behave like **lemmings** or like the **sheep of Panurge** (*Rabelais - France - 16th Century*)

[image]

You may also say that they are "blind followers".

Comment: Yes a co-worker also mentioned both _sheep_ and _lemmings_ (and of course _sheeple_, in jest). But those imply flocking or herd behavior, and here it's small groups or couples that each choose to act out a more complex thing on their own.  One poses, another photographs it. It's carefully and individually staged, not just follow-the-leader.

Answer (score 1):

**Herd mentality**?

> Herd mentality, or mob mentality, describes how people are influenced
>   by their peers to adopt certain behaviors, follow trends, and/or
>   purchase items. Examples of the herd mentality include stock market
>   trends, superstition and home décor. Social psychologists study the
>   related topics of group intelligence, crowd wisdom, and decentralized
>   decision making. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_mentality)

Also - **Clichéd Photo Poses**

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite capture the silly or superficial aspect of what you're getting at, but you could just use *tradition* (or *silly tradition*):

> a long-established or inherited way of thinking or acting: *The rebellious students wanted to break with tradition.*

If you want to be a little different you could go with *instituition* (or *silly*/*cultural* *institution*):

> a well-established and structured pattern of behavior or of relationships that is accepted as a fundamental part of a culture, as marriage: *the institution of the family.*

Source: dictionary.com